# intermittent bad gateway django mysql error

Tags: python, mysql, django

My error is intermittent, and occurs on all pages, so for now the only code I will paste is the settings for my database.

```
    DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'hms',
        'USER': 'hms',
        'PASSWORD': '27Kovelov',
        'HOST': '127.0.0.1',
        'PORT': '3306',
        'OPTIONS': {'init_command': "SET sql_mode='STRICT_TRANS_TABLES'"},
    }
}
```

I'm getting the following error message from django:

```
(2003, "Can't connect to MySQL server on '127.0.0.1:3306' (111)")
```

or I get a `Bad Gateway` error message in my browser.

I have a separate application that writes scientific data to a mysql database that resides on my web hosting plan (digitalocean droplet). Is it possible the django error message is because my app the writes the data  and my django app are accessing the database at the same time?

Answer (score 0):

Error 111 means the host and/or mysql service is not reachable. So, first, just check if it is working normally via mysql client command like below:

```
mysql -u hms -p27Kovelov hms
```